# Preciso de uma ajuda!

Tags: java

Comecei a estudar orientação a objetos e preciso de uma ajuda.
Nao estou entendendo a pergunta alguém poderia me ajudar.

Com as classes Cliente e Pessoa:
a. criar uma instância de cliente
b. criar uma instância de pessoa
c. criar um ArrayList de Clientes
d. adicionar a instância de cliente criada em (a) no ArrayList.
e. adicionar a instância de pessoa criada em (b) no ArrayList.

Comment: Não está entendendo o enunciado? Pelo que está descrito, dá a se entender que você tenha que cria uma classe `Pessoa`, uma classe `Cliente` que estende Pessoa (implícito), criar uma instancia de Pessoa, uma instancia de Cliente, uma instancia de `ArrayList` que irá armazenar tanto a pessoa como o cliente, e então adiciona-los a lista. Como Cliente estende Pessoa, você pode declarar o seu ArrayList como `ArrayList<Pessoa>`, dessa forma quando recuperar um objeto existente nele, terá garantia de que o objeto possuirá os atributos e métodos de Pessoa.

Answer (score 1):

levando em conta que o classe Cliente esteja estendendo pessoa..

```
ArrayList<Pessoa> array = new ArrayList<>();
 array.add(new Pessoa());
 array.add(new Cliente());
```